# Is there any way to improve the performance of the denoising autoencoder?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I am trying to train a denoising autoencoder to denoise with an image composed of two simple lines as input. However, even when using a simple image like this, it does not output a good output.What's more mysterious is that it perfectly removes noise when inputting a single linear image data as an input.

I used a general convolutional autoencoder structure using the leakyReLU function, and the code is down below.

Even if I increase the number of training data given as input or increase the training epoch, the result is always the same.

Any suggestions on how to increase the performance of the denoising autoencoder would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Convolutional Auto Encoder code:

```
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
    import numpy as np

    class ConvAutoencoder:
        @staticmethod
        def build(width, height, depth, filters=(32, 64), latentDim = 16):
            # initialize the input shape to be "channels last" along with
            # the channels dimension itself
            # channels dimension itself
            inputShape = (height, width, depth)
            chanDim = -1

            # define the input to the encoder
            inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
            x = inputs

    # loop over the number of filters
            for f in filters:
                # apply a CONV => RELU => BN operation
                x = Conv2D(f, (3, 3), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
                x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
                x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)


            # flatten the network and then construct our latent vector
            volumeSize = K.int_shape(x)
            x = Flatten()(x)
            latent = Dense(latentDim)(x)
            # build the encoder model
            encoder = Model(inputs, latent, name="encoder")

    # start building the decoder model which will accept the
            # output of the encoder as its inputs
            latentInputs = Input(shape=(latentDim,))
            x = Dense(np.prod(volumeSize[1:]))(latentInputs)
            x = Reshape((volumeSize[1], volumeSize[2], volumeSize[3]))(x)
            # loop over our number of filters again, but this time in
            # reverse order
            for f in filters[::-1]:
                # apply a CONV_TRANSPOSE => RELU => BN operation
                x = Conv2DTranspose(f, (3, 3), strides=2,
                    padding="same")(x)
                x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
                x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
            # apply a single CONV_TRANSPOSE layer used to recover the
            # original depth of the image
            x = Conv2DTranspose(depth, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
            outputs = Activation("sigmoid")(x)
            # build the decoder model
            decoder = Model(latentInputs, outputs, name="decoder")
            # our autoencoder is the encoder + decoder
            autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoder(encoder(inputs)),
                name="autoencoder")
            # return a 3-tuple of the encoder, decoder, and autoencoder
            return (encoder, decoder, autoencoder)
```

input and output images : [image: The upper figure is the input image and the lower figure is the output image.]

Comment: This is where experimentation starts coming in. You might see better results training without sigmoid, then just do a short thresholding afterwards. Or, the easiest way is to use a hough transform immediately on the image, as that'll almost definitely find these lines.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to not use the sigmoid function, and use a lower threshold? Do you mean to use the relu function in the last layer of the encoder instead of sigmoid function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to preserve local information in autoencoder. This way is using a Convolution as last layer of Encoder. Thus you shouldn't use Flatten and Dense layer's and you should create a encoder latents space using output volumes from convolutions

Code,

```
input_shape = ...#your shape   
input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Encoder
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")(x)

# Decoder
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=2, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)

# Autoencoder
autoencoder = Model(input, x)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
autoencoder.summary()
```